# Stenciljs throwing build error from @types/babel__traverse package after fresh install

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, stenciljs

So for context, I have just installed stencil. And was wanting to mess around with it. I'm using latest version from the docs "npm install -g @stencil/core@latest --save-exact" and when I ran it the first time with `npm start`, It threw a bunch of errors and complained about missing library. So I ran `npm install` it fixed all those errors but now it throws a new error, when I try to run it. Keep in mind I have not edited or added any of my own code to the project. Error below. [image] Ignore the border thats my screenshot tool)

[ ERROR ]  TypeScript: ./node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts:321:6
An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.

```
L320:      // this is good enough for non-visitor traverse options e.g. `noScope`
L321:      [k: `${string}|${string}`]: VisitNode<S, Node>;
L322:  };
```

[01:19.3]  build failed, watching for changes... in 2.96 s`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known issue with @types/babel__traverse v7.21.0 and later. We worked around the issue by installing v7.20.0.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/babel__traverse@7.20.0
```

and then modifying the package.json to remove the `^`:

```
"@types/babel__traverse": "7.20.0"
```

Comment: Awesome this worked thank you. I am surprised this was allowed to slip through and into the the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to globally install @stencil/core (I don't know of any advantage).

Instead you can [initialise a new Stencil project with `npm init stencil`](https://stenciljs.com/docs/getting-started#running-the-create-stencil-cli) which will ask for the starter project (component or app) and the project name. I just tried that and it works without problem.

I'm not familiar with the error you're receiving, but I'm guessing installing Stencil globally has something to do with it.

I suggest you try:

```bash
npm uninstall -g @stencil/core
npm init stencil component stencil-test-project
cd stencil-test-project
npm install
npm start
```

This should create a new project, start the dev server and open the browser.