# Stencil starter errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-component, stenciljs

i wanted to try stencil.js. I followed the "Get Started" from their docs, but there are some errors and i can´t find a solution.

**What i did**
`npm init stencil`
`cd projekt && npm install && npm start`

Below is an screenshot of what is happening.
[image]

I thought its because of Typescript 3.6, so i added it to the Project, also updated it to the newest version. Even my global typescript in both versions didnt work.

Just with that errors, i dont find a solution.
Also, the solution mentioned here didnt help -> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76685856/stenciljs-throwing-build-error-after-fresh-install](https://stackoverflow.com)

Someone has an idea how to solve this problem?

**Edit**
The solution that worked for me was adding

```
"skipLibCheck: true"
```

to my tsconfig
[enter link description here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck)

Comment: Why did you select Stencil?

Comment: Based on the output there, it looks like you're using the Stencil compiler to try to build your project (based on `stencil build --dev --watch --serve` at the top of the terminal screenshot). The Stencil compiler is picking up Webpack typings and reporting type incompatibilities here. Can you add your project structure and the versions of the packages you're using? Stencil alone shouldn't require webpack, but if this is part of a larger project where another project is consuming your Stencil compiled components, then I could see why you'd want a bundler like webpack.

Comment: There is no real project structure. its just an empty folder where i followed the docs (https://stenciljs.com/docs/getting-started).

Comment: I do see the types are resolving several levels above your stencil project (`../../../../node_modules/` in the error messages). Can you try to run `npm init stencil@latest` in a different directory (one that is not a child of `../../../..`)?

Comment: Yeah, i wondered about that as well. it trys to use typescript from my global node_modules.. but i found a solution, added as in my post